# Force Telegram to open invite link internally

Tags: telegram-bot

I have designed a bot that manages user joinning to specific channels in which bot is administrator. In my code I have used **Inlinekeyboard** buttons that simulates invite link clicking.
Problem is the way that telegram behaves the links. It opens the links using phone browser and it is not user friendly at all.
How can I prevent telegram from openning invite links in phone browser?

Comment: Do you mean 'In-App Browser'? If so, I think you can't force Telegram to do that due to user preferences, which allow the user to choose.